# eslint - no unused expressions error with fancybox initialisation

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to initialise fancybox so I use the following code:

```js
$gallery
  .fancybox({
    caption: (instance, item) => {           // <-- error on this line
      `<div class="fancybox-download-image">
            <h3 class="fancybox-download-image__title">Download Image</h3>
            <div class="fancybox-download-image__text">
              <p class="fancybox-download-image__paragraph">By downloading this asset you are agreeing to our <a href="/legal/image-license" class="license-opener" target="_blank">image license terms</a>.</p>
              <a href="${item.src}" class="btn btn--cta btn--download">Download image</a>
            </div>
          </div>`
    },
  });
```

However, this throws the following error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

I have had a look at the [documentation about this rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions) and as usual, it's not very clear what I'm meant to do to fix the error

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not sure if related (might be), but you either need to add `return` before your string literal, or remove the curly brackets. Right now, your callback neither returns nor does anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the eslint documentation on `no-unused-expressions` :

> An unused expression which has no effect on the state of the program indicates a logic error.

And indeed, your callback

```
(instance, item) => {           // <-- error on this line
  `<div class="fancybox-download-image">
        <h3 class="fancybox-download-image__title">Download Image</h3>
        <div class="fancybox-download-image__text">
          <p class="fancybox-download-image__paragraph">By downloading this asset you are agreeing to our <a href="/legal/image-license" class="license-opener" target="_blank">image license terms</a>.</p>
          <a href="${item.src}" class="btn btn--cta btn--download">Download image</a>
        </div>
      </div>`
}
```

actually does not do anything.

You need to return your string literal, either by adding the `return` keyword, or by removing the curly brackets :

```
(instance, item) => `<div class="fancybox-download-image">
    <h3 class="fancybox-download-image__title">Download Image</h3>
    <div class="fancybox-download-image__text">
      <p class="fancybox-download-image__paragraph">By downloading this asset you are agreeing to our <a href="/legal/image-license" class="license-opener" target="_blank">image license terms</a>.</p>
      <a href="${item.src}" class="btn btn--cta btn--download">Download image</a>
    </div>
  </div>`
```

or :

```
(instance, item) => {
    return `<div class="fancybox-download-image">
        <h3 class="fancybox-download-image__title">Download Image</h3>
        <div class="fancybox-download-image__text">
          <p class="fancybox-download-image__paragraph">By downloading this asset you are agreeing to our <a href="/legal/image-license" class="license-opener" target="_blank">image license terms</a>.</p>
          <a href="${item.src}" class="btn btn--cta btn--download">Download image</a>
        </div>
      </div>`
}
```

There are effectively no difference between those 2 syntaxes. However, the "no curly brackets" one can only be used with arrow functions, and when there is only a single statement which value will be returned.